# Node js large number of outbound http requests

Tags: node.js

I have an node js express app. One of the endpoints in my app serves as a proxy to an external web service. When running a stress test with 2000 users per second directly against the external service, the response time was only 50ms. However, when running the same test against my endpoint, the response time was about 3 seconds. This is strange because when testing my app against an empty endpoint that simply returns 200 right away, the average response time is about 150ms.

Basically I'm just using the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and all I do is to forward the requests to the external service. I tried playing with the maxSockets parameter of the http module, but without results. Here is my setting:

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;

var request = require('request'); 

var options = {
   uri: params.SERVICE_URL,
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/json' },
   json: bodyOfRequest
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   // return response to client
}
```

Also, I'm running the code as a web app in Azure.

Comment: Can you pipe the response directly back from the `request()` so `request()` doesn't have to buffer the whole request before returning it?  That could definitely improve responsiveness.  It would help if we could see the context for the above `request()` operation and what, if anything, you are doing on the response before sending it back.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't quite understand what you mean about piping, though the term is familiar from streams. Can you give an example in code? and regarding your second question, I don't do anything with the response - I simply return it to the client with a status of 200.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of `.pipe()` right in the [`request()` doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) including several that are just piping the request back to a response from an http server.   If you want further help with how your code should use it, you'd have to show us more of your code in your question so we could see how the `request()` call is inside an http request and how you're sending the results of the `request()` call back as a response.  `.pipe()` would definitely be preferable.  I don't know how much of an impact it will have on your performance, but worth doing.